# spaCy use only some components

Tags: spacy

I am using spaCy for my project. It works magnificiently, only it is a bit time-consuming. I am looking for ways to reduce processing time. I have realized that calling `nlp` on my `text` will perform many operations: tokenization, ner, ... (doc here: https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#pipelines) ; while in some parts of my code, I only need to perform e.g. vectorization. Is it possible to apply only some components of the pipeline to reduce processing time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to disable modules and enable them back when necessary. When speeding up really is an issue, try using the pipe functionality, this speeds up for loads of documents.

```py
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
    for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, disable=["tagger", "parser"]):
        print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
```

[Source](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines)

Comment: Wow, looks like it has divided processing time by 30! I'll go with the simpler `nlp(text, disable = ...)` sentence though; not sure what is the use of the `pipe` generator

Comment: The pipe generator is able to split the processes up, which creates batches and speeds up the process even more! So when you have 1000 articles to go through, it batches these articles up in n-size and spawns multiple workers. For smaller sets, the startup time for pipe function is taking too long sometimes.
Conclusion, loads of data use the pipe, small amounts of data don't use the pipe.